# CustomTextView canvas not drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, custom-component

Drawable not drawing in custom TextView. Can anyone please help me in sorting the problem out. What i was trying to build is a texview that shows progress. The below mention code is just a sample.

```
public class ProgressableTextview extends TextView {

    Paint mPaint;
    int mProgress = 70;
    int maxProgress = 100;
    int mRadiud = 10;

    public ProgressableTextview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ProgressableTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ProgressableTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, (mProgress/maxProgress)*getWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), mPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getLeft(), 0);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code, and `TextView` is visible and filled with gray color. What's the problem?

Comment: yes that gray color is appearing but rectangle is not drawing.

Comment: Thanks @Fox in Socks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out what was the problem, it was the mistake in drawRect function. drawRect function need to changed as :

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, ((float) mProgress/maxProgress) * getWidth(), getMeasureHeight(), mPaint);
```

since mProgress was a integer dividing it by integer returns zero and that was the problem.